# NuGet and distributed version control (DVCS)

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs, nuget

I wonder if it is possible to use nuget to only store references to the required packages in version control (only the package.config and ignore the packages folder).

Is there a way to tell nuget to (re)download all the referenced packages in the various package.config files? Or something similar which could be put into a build script.

**Update:**

Seems that I'm not the only one who requested this feature: [See this work item](http://nupack.codeplex.com/workitem/165) (thanks to PHeiberg for the hint)

**Update 2:**

NuGet now has this feature builtin. See [Using NuGet without committing packages to source control](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages#Using_NuGet_without_committing_packages_to_source_control) for details. All left is to add the packages directory to .gitignore or some equivalent of your VCS (`/packages/` will do the trick if you have it in the root of your repository and are using git).

Comment: @Robert-ros answers this with the blog entry from David Ebbo. :-) http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/08/easy-way-to-set-up-nuget-to-restore.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just found out about NuGetPowerTools: https://github.com/davidfowl/NuGetPowerTools

Also see: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/08/easy-way-to-set-up-nuget-to-restore.html

Update: NuGet 1.6 now supports Package Restore: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-1.6

Answer (score 8):

I don't know about your first question.

As for having a CI server automatically update the packages, it's doable in theory. You could chain the "List-Package -Installed" and the "Update-Package" commands and have each package updated to the latest version. See the [command reference](http://nupack.codeplex.com/documentation?title=Package%20Manager%20Console%20Command%20Reference) for further details.

Scott Guthrie [says this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/06/announcing-nupack-asp-net-mvc-3-beta-and-webmatrix-beta-2.aspx#7624506) on the topic:

> "You can integrate the command-line
>   option with a CI solution and do an
>   update-package command explicitly as
>   part of your build/CI process to pull
>   down updates.  Frankly I'm not sure
>   that makes sense for the scenarios we
>   are talking about, though, as
>   typically you want some dev to decide
>   before updating a core runtime
>   dependency to a new version.  NuPack's
>   default model would have a developer
>   use NuPack to install a library - and
>   NuPack would automatically check in
>   the package and dependencies to source
>   control.  That way another dev (or the
>   CI server) wouldn't need to use NuPack
>   again - they could just sync their
>   source and build.  But as I mentioned
>   earlier - if you wanted to explicitly
>   do an update as part of your CI
>   process you could."

**Edit:**

After your comment I see what you're trying to achieve. I found [this long thread](http://nupack.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=230110) in the NuPack discussions list about the issue. A solution will apparently not be part of v1. A custom build task in the CI of your choice and a config in your repo for it is the only solution I see. Please report back with your findings. You got me interested.

Comment: Well I don't want the latest version, I want the specified one - I just don't want the binaries in the repository (as it bloats the repository size of a DCVS repository with each new version considerably)

Comment: Ok, that kind of makes sense. You could stick a list of package names and versions in the repository and then have your CI fetch each of those with an "Add-Package -Version" command.

Comment: Thanks for the link, if i find something I'll post it here. Meanwhile I will leave this question open until a solution is found.

Answer (score 5):

There is a current discussion about this question at [Phil Haack's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/27/feedback-request-for-using-nuget-without-committing-packages.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20haacked%20%28you%27ve%20been%20HAACKED%29), where he is asking for feedback on how to tackle this question.